# How do I use NSubstitute to mock ILogger on a constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have the following concrete controller constructor:

```
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserRepository<User> _userRepository;
    private readonly ILogger<AuthenticationController> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;


    public AuthenticationController(IUserRepository<User> userRepository, ILogger<AuthenticationController> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }
```

I'm trying to mock the constructor, but seem to be having trouble with ILogger.

```
 var userRepository = Substitute.For<IUserRepository<User>>();
 var config = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();
 var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();

 var controller = new AuthenticationController(userRepository, logger, config);
```

With logger I've tried the following, but all continue to leave a 'red line' under the Constructor : eg. on the line

```
var controller = new AuthenticationController(userRepository, logger, config);
```

AuthenticationController has the red line regardless of what I try.

If I declare logger in the form:
`var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<AuthenticationController>>();` the whole right side of = also red lines.

```
var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<AuthenticationController>>();
```

then I've tried:

```
var auth = Substitute.For<AuthenticationController>();
var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<auth>>();
```

When I hover over the red line it mentions that the assembly reference on the api is higher than the unit tests assembly. Both projects target .Net Core 2.1

This is the error generating from my test project:

> Assembly 'My.Api' with identity 'My.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

My test project references my api project. The api project has a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (2.1.1)` My unit test project does not have a direct reference at all to this library.

Comment: Well, I've never used `Substitute` but in `Moq` framework you pass the object `Mock.Object` or in your scenario - `logger.Object` rather than the mock itself

Comment: When you used `For<ILogger<AuthenticationController>>` what did the error say? That should have worked as far as I can tell.

Comment: What error do you get (the red line)? From my perspective `Substitute.For<ILogger<AuthenticationController>>();` should work.

Comment: You may be using the wrong ILogger. Check if your namespaces match.

Comment: @MikeZboray I have updated my question

Comment: check references and update the one referenced by the test

Comment: Could you please include the compiler error message in the question?

Comment: @DavidTchepak Question updated as per request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, I created a new test project in the solution and still received the same error. So, in my original test project I installed specifically via Nuget the

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core (2.1.1) package

and my error's went away and it run successfully. I have not specifically referenced this in my Api Project. I've put this up in-case others run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your code project and your unit test project use the same version of the nuget package containing the ILogger.

Comment: In both projects, If I right mouse click and select 'Go To Definition' both go to the same file  `Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60`

Comment: That's strange. Have you checked in the NuGet package manager?